# Converting a string to uint8_t array in C++

Tags: c++, ns-3

I want an std::string object (such as a name) to a uint8_t array in C++. The
function `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>` rejects my string. And since I'm coding using NS-3, some warnings are being interpreted as errors.

Comment: Show your code.  What do you mean by "string object"?  std::string or a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want a pointer to the `string`'s data:

```
reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&myString[0])
```

If you want a copy of the `string`'s data:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> myVector(myString.begin(), myString.end());
uint8_t *p = &myVector[0];
```

Comment: That could in theory not be null terminated

Comment: reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(myString.c_str()) would work though (assuming myString is a std::string).

Comment: @awoodland -- correct, but nul termination was not a requirement of the question. And, given that he wants `uint8_t`, not `char`, it is safe to assume he doesn't want a C-style string.

Comment: +1: The `std::vector` is great stuff. Creates a simple copy without memcpy or other C style stuff that likes to pop up in answers to these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Rob: use `.c_str()` instead of `&myString[0]` since `std::string` is not _required_ to be contiguous.

Comment: @awoodland: While in C++03 it might not be null terminated, in C++11 the standard requires null termination of the buffer.

Comment: @rubenvb: Interstingly, chances are that the code above ends up using `memmove` (maybe even `memcpy`) under the hood.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - Good point, I'd forgotten that change in amongst all the really obvious ones!

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yes, `std::string` is not required to be contiguous, but `std::string::operator[]` is. From [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/#comment-483): "[C++2003] does require &str[0] to cough up a pointer to contiguous string data (but not necessarily null-terminated!)" See **lib.string.ops** and **lib.string.access**.

Comment: @Rob: I was told C++03 did not require it.  However, I see it in C++11 at least. §21.4.1 / 5 `...for any basic_string object s, the identity &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n shall hold for all values of n such that 0 <= n < s.size().`

Comment: MooingDuck, Rob: C++11 `std::string` has contiguous storage, and if you glue the different parts together (ie the `.c_str()` function has to be O(1), so no copying the buffer), `&s[0]` and the `std::string::data()´ function gives you a null-terminated character array nonetheless. On the other hand, all popular current (pre-c++11) implementations do have contiguous `std::string` storage...

Comment: David: I know it does that under the hood, it just hides the fragile and unnecessary details away so the code is a lot more readable and bugs for such operations become non-existant.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that uint8_t has the same representation as char? If not, why is this valid?

Answer (score 14):

String objects have a `.c_str()` member function that returns a `const char*`. This pointer can be cast to a `const uint8_t*`:

```
std::string name("sth");

const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(name.c_str());
```

Note that this pointer will only be valid as long as the original string object isn't modified or destroyed.

Comment: Is there a way to do it backwards? For example, I would like to cast the uint8_t array to a c_str. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you need an actual array (not a pointer, as other answers have suggested; the difference is explained very nicely in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914794/2886839)), you need to use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::string str = "foo";
uint8_t arr[32];
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::begin(arr));
```