# C++ Error: Incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [2]

Tags: c++, error-handling, char

I have a bit of a problem with my constructor. 
In my header file I declare:

```
char short_name_[2];
```

- and other variables

In my constructor:

```
Territory(std::string name, char short_name[2], Player* owner, char units);
void setShortName(char* short_name);
inline const char (&getShortName() const)[2] { return short_name_; }
```

In my cpp file:

```
Territory::Territory(std::string name, char short_name[2], Player* owner, 
                     char units) : name_(name), short_name_(short_name), 
                    owner_(owner), units_(units)
{ }
```

My error:

> Territory.cpp: In constructor ‘Territory::Territory(std::string,
>   char*, Player*, char)’: Territory.cpp:15:33: error: incompatible types
>   in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [2]’

I already figured out that `char[2] <=> char*` but I'm not sure how to handle this about my constructor and get/setters.

Comment: `I already figured out that char[2] <=> char* ` not really.

Comment: but i thought for the c++ compiler is char[2] equivalent to char* ?! i really have no idea how to init this constructor and the getters corretly...

Comment: Arrays and pointers are *very* different things. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); the rules in this area are essentially the same for C and C++.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Raw arrays in C++ are kind of annoying and fraught with peril. This is why unless you have a very good reason to you should use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

First off, as others have said, `char[2]` is not the same as `char*`, or at least not usually. `char[2]` is a size 2 array of `char` and `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. They often get confused because arrays will decay to a pointer to the first element whenever they need to. So this works:

```
char foo[2];
char* bar = foo;
```

But the reverse does not:

```
const char* bar = "hello";
const char foo[6] = bar; // ERROR
```

Adding to the confusion, when declaring function parameters, `char[]` is equivalent to `char*`. So in your constructor the parameter `char short_name[2]` is really `char* short_name`.

Another quirk of arrays is that they cannot be copied like other types (this is one explanation for why arrays in function parameters are treated as pointers). So for example I can *not* do something like this:

```
char foo[2] = {'a', 'b'};
char bar[2] = foo;
```

Instead I have to iterate over the elements of `foo` and copy them into `bar`, or use some function which does that for me such as [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
char foo[2] = {'a', 'b'};
char bar[2];
// std::begin and std::end are only available in C++11
std::copy(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo), std::begin(bar));
```

So in your constructor you have to manually copy the elements of `short_name` into `short_name_`:

```
Territory::Territory(std::string name, char* short_name, Player* owner, 
                     char units) : name_(name), owner_(owner), units_(units)
{ 
    // Note that std::begin and std::end can *not* be used on pointers.
    std::copy(short_name, short_name + 2, std::begin(short_name));
}
```

As you can see this is all very annoying, so unless you have a very good reason you just should use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays (or in this case probably `std::string`).

Answer (score 2):

When a function wants an array as argument, it gets a pointer to the first element of an array instead. This pointer cannot be used to initialize an array, because it's a pointer, not an array.

You can write functions that accept *references* to arrays as arguments:

```
void i_dont_accept_pointers(const char (array&)[2]) {}
```

The problem here is, that this array reference cannot be used to initialize another array.

```
class Foo {
  char vars[2];
  Foo(const char (args&)[2])
    : vars(args)  // This will not work
  {}
};
```

C++ 11 introduced `std::array` to eliminiate this and other problems of arrays. In older versions, you will have to iterate through the array elements and copy them individually or use `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ as C holds most of the rules of C.

In case of C, always use char* to pass array because that how C looks at it. Even `sizeof (short_name_)` will be 8 or 4 when passed to function.
Now, you have a space of 2 bytes in variable `short_name_`

Constructor allocated memory for two bytes in `short_name_` and you need to copy the bytes into that or use a char * pointer and assume it's size if 2.

Chapter 9  from **Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets** is good read to understand it.

For simplicity this could be C style code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Territory {
    private:
        string s;
        char c[2];
    public:
    Territory(std::string a, char b[2] /*visualize as char *b*/) {
        s  = a;
        c[0] = b[0]; //or use strcpy
        c[1] = b[1];
    }
    void PrintMe() {
        printf ("As string %s as char %c or %s\n",this->s.c_str(), c[0],c);
    }
};


main () {
    Territory a("hello", "h");
    a.PrintMe();
}
```

Comment: It's 2020 and buffer overflows are still a thing. I think examples/comments should reflect strncpy() instead of that classic strcpy(), particularly where beginners are looking.